# awk output with spaces in first column

Tags: awk

I tried using awk splitting the columns to print a sentence but the first column has spaces.

Sample of my beginner code:

```
$ awk '/Linux/ { print "The filename","\""$1"\"","is located in",$2 }' test.txt
The filename "The" is located in test
The filename "Some" is located in file
The filename "File" is located in name
The filename "Something_here" is located in /ABC
The filename "Another_test" is located in /DEFG
The filename "Label" is located in test
```

From file: test.txt

```
Filename                               Folder         Type
-------------------------------------- -------------- ------
The test file                          /test/folder   Linux
Some file                              /              Linux
File name                              /Temp          Linux
Something_here                         /ABC           Linux
Another_test                           /DEFG          Linux
Label test                             /HIJK          Linux
```

what I want to achieve: (with quotes inclusive)

```
The filename "Default file" is located in / 
The filename "The test file" is located in /test/folder
```

issue is when i use 'space' or '/' as delimiter i cannot get the whole line when printing

Comment: Kindly provide, the script or command you are using. Also, the output you are getting now.

Comment: @KimochiIku you can edit your post. please move the content of your comment to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU AWK, this should do the trick:

```
awk 'match($0, /([^\/]+)([^ ]+) *Linux/, arr) { sub(/ +$/, "", arr[1]); printf("The filename \"%s\" is located in %s\n", arr[1], arr[2]) }' test.txt
```

Explanation:

```
# match and store groups in 'arr'
#  - arr[1]: everything up until the first slash (including a lot of whitespace)
#  - arr[2]: first slash until space
#  - rest: also ensure there's 'Linux' after that
match($0, /([^\/]+)([^ ]+) *Linux/, arr) {

  # trim whitespace from the right hand side of the filename
  sub(/ +$/, "", arr[1]);

  # print
  printf("The filename \"%s\" is located in %s\n", arr[1], arr[2])
}
```

Note that there is also a less powerful version of `match` in other flavors of AWK and the same thing could be achieve with those, but you'd have to write a bit more code.

Comment: this works! are these arr[] called subarrays? never used the command match before, can you use == or are they different?

Comment: `arr` is one array with multiple values in it. eg. at position 1 (`arr[1]`) the filename is stored. you can do things like `arr[1] == "mystring"` if you want to compare the contents. If you're in a terminal, you can also type `man awk` and it will give you tons of information about this :)

Also, since this works for you, can you please accept the answer? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would propose [**sed**](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#Command_002dLine-Options) with the substitution based on regular expression and back references plus a [**grep**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) command to eliminate the header lines of the source file:

```
$ cat test.txt | grep -E 'Linux[ ]*$' | sed -E 's%(.+)([^ ])([ ]+)(/.+)[ ]+Linux[ ]*$%The filename "\1\2" is located in \4%'
The filename "The test file" is located in /test/folder  
The filename "Some file" is located in /             
The filename "File name" is located in /Temp         
The filename "Something_here" is located in /ABC          
The filename "Another_test" is located in /DEFG         
The filename "Label test" is located in /HIJK
```

A good reference for the regular expressions (*regex*) is in the [Linux manuals](https://linux.die.net/man/7/regex)

The detailed description as requested in the comment:

- **grep** with **-E** option accepts the extended *regex* (reference document above). Here it is used to filter the lines containing "Linux" word followed by some spaces if any at the end of each line
- The output of **grep** goes into the input of **sed**
- **sed** is passed the **-E** option like **grep** to accept extended *regex*. The **s** command substitutes a characters matching the *regex* (first part between % chars = "(.+)([^ ])([ ]+)(/.+)[ ]+Linux[ ]*$") by others (second part between % chars = "The filename "\1\2" is located in \4").
- The second part uses back references: '\' followed by a nonzero decimal digit **n** is substituted by the **n**th parenthesized sub-expression of the *regex*. Here, \1 is substituted by the string which matches the 1st "(.+)" which is the filename here, \2 is substituted by the following "([^ ])" which is the last char of the filename (trick to suppress the following blanks from the name)...

This is not a rigorous explanation but at least it provides some inputs to go farther.

Another solution is to pass multiple actions on the **sed** command line. Hence, you can add a query to delete the first 2 header lines to suppress the pipe with **cat** and **grep**. Here "1,2d', means "delete lines numbers 1 and 2":

```
$ sed -E '1,2d;s%(.+)([^ ])([ ]+)(/.+)[ ]+Linux[ ]*$%The filename "\1\2" is located in \4%' test.txt
The filename "The  test file" is located in /test/folder  
The filename "Some file" is located in /             
The filename "File name" is located in /Temp         
The filename "Something_here" is located in /ABC          
The filename "Another_test" is located in /DEFG         
The filename "Label test" is located in /HIJK
```

NOTES: According to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#Command_002dLine-Options), the **-E** option switches to using extended regular expressions. It has been supported for years by GNU **sed**, and is now included in POSIX.
On older systems, **-r** may be used if **-E** is not supported:

```
$ sed -r '1,2d;s%(.+)([^ ])([ ]+)(/.+)[ ]+Linux[ ]*$%The filename "\1\2" is located in \4%' test.txt
The filename "The  test file" is located in /test/folder  
The filename "Some file" is located in /             
The filename "File name" is located in /Temp         
The filename "Something_here" is located in /ABC          
The filename "Another_test" is located in /DEFG         
The filename "Label test" is located in /HIJK
```

Comment: Would you be able to break down your command on what/how did it work? Does awk with while read in this work too?

Comment: I updated the answer to explain the sed command line.

Comment: sed: invalid option -- 'E'
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...
 sed --version
GNU sed version 4.1.5

Comment: My sed command is newer : sed (GNU sed) 4.7. Is the "-r" option supported ? It is synonymous to -E.

Comment: yea tried sed with -r works, thanks! but was looking to learn how to do this in awk option

Comment: I updated the answer to make it with only one sed command without cat and grep (end of the answer). This is more efficient as there are less processes. For awk, there are some other responses ;-)

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk has regex field separators, so just require multiple spaces separating your columns.

```
awk '/Linux/ { print "The file \""$1"\" is in "$2"." }' FS="   *" test.txt
```

It also offers fixed-width fields, say `info gawk fieldwidths`, you could use the lengths of the dash lines to set those on the fly.

Comment: Nice but it does not auto-adapt to blanks in the file names. If you have " The <more than one space> test file" as filename, this specific command line will not work.

Comment: The data format is inadequate to deal with that anyway, trailing blanks in file names are undetectable.  The leading-blanks possibility was why I mentioned fieldwidths.

Comment: I was speaking about blanks inside the name, not the leading and trailing ones... But names like this except may be some sound files embedding their title in their name, are quite weird...